# Platform specific import component in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am using react native with typescript. I have a component with the following structure

```
component
    - component.ios.tsx
    - component.android.tsx
```

Now I want to import the component. So, I am doing this:

```
import component from '../component/component';
```

But it says:

```
[ts] Cannot find module ../component/component
```

The location is correct. I need to add something to the tslint file to make it understand.

I also tried to do:

```
let component = require('../component/component');
```

This didn't give typescript error. But it gave a runtime error.

```
element type is invalid expected a string or a class/function but got undefined
```

Has anybody run into this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

One way of doing it, which is a bit annoying, is creating a declaration file with the same name.

```
component
- component.d.ts   <---
- component.android.tsx
- component.ios.tsx
```

then

```js
import { file } from "../group/file";
```

**Update:**
Another way of doing it is just omit the extension for one of them, then typescript will pick up the default one.

- component.tsx
- component.android.tsx

Android will pick up the specific android file, and iOS will default to normal one.

Answer (score 14):

add following line in tsconfig.json file

```
"moduleSuffixes": [".ios", ".android", ".native", ""],
```

Comment: That's correct and should be the top answer. Note however that this option should be under `compilerOptions`.

Answer (score 8):

With last version of React you can use *Suspense* and *lazy* to avoid over typings etc., for example if I want a component **Touchable** with specific code for iOS and Android, my structure will looks like that:

```
- Touchable
   - index.tsx
   - Touchable.android.tsx
   - Touchable.ios.tsx
   - types.d.ts
```

And on index.tsx the code will looks like that:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native';

import { TouchableProps } from './types.d';

const TouchableComponent = lazy(() =>
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? import('./Touchable.ios')
    : import('./Touchable.android'),
);

const Touchable: FunctionComponent<TouchableProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<View />}>
      <TouchableComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Touchable;
```

So anywhere on my app I want to use this component, I just have to do that:

```
import Touchable from './path/to/Touchable';

[...]
<Touchable>
  <Text>Touchable text</Text>
</Touchable>
[...]
```

Types.d.ts :

```
export type TouchableSizeType = 'small' | 'regular' | 'big';
export type TouchableType = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'success' | 'error' | 'warning';

export interface TouchableProps {
  disabled?: boolean;
  size?: TouchableSizeType;
  type?: TouchableType;
  onClick?: (event?: Event) => Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: how types.d.ts should look like?

Comment: I've just edit my response to add an exemple of types.d.ts file, hope it help

Comment: OK this is working fine ... and I like it ...Did you have any troubles with it? I have worry because Suspense is (still) experimental...

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that your component name is ProgressBar, so create `index.d.ts` and adjust your code below in index.d.ts

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import {Constructor, NativeMethodsMixin} from 'react-native';

export interface ProgressBarProps {
  progress: number;
}

declare class ProgressBarComponent extends Component<ProgressBarProps> {}

declare const ProgressBarBase: Constructor<NativeMethodsMixin> &
  typeof ProgressBarComponent;

export default class ProgressBar extends ProgressBarBase {}
```

So your component folder should looks like

```
component/
 - index.android.tsx
 - index.ios.tsx
 - index.d.ts
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! The other answers confused me, heh. For those who don't understand, `filename.d.ts` is basically the file that TypeScript will look at when determining what the type is when you're trying to import. So in that file just export the correct type for the thing you're exporting (whatever that may be) and then TypeScript will be satisfied, stop complaining, and properly type your import.

Answer (score 2):

Folder:

```
component/
  - Test
    - index.android.tsx
    - index.ios.tsx
    - index.d.ts
    - types.d.ts
  - index.ts
```

Test/index.android.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { TestProps } from './types';

function Test(props: TestProps) {
    return <Text>Test android</Text>;
}

export default Test;
```

Test/index.ios.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { TestProps } from './types';

function Test(props: TestProps) {
    return <Text>Test ios</Text>;
}

export default Test;
```

Test/index.d.ts:

```
import { TestProps } from './types';
export default function Test(props: TestProps): React.JSX.Element;
```

component/index.ts:

```
export { default as Test } from './components/Test';
```

use Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from '@components';

function PageA() {
    return <Test />
}

export default PageA;
```

I've got this TypeScript code running without complaints and with the right types.

Answer (score 0):

It all makes sense, since file at `../component/component.tsx` does not exists.

Haven't tried, but this could learn TS to understand such imports

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "*": ["*", "*.ios", "*.android"]
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. TypeScript 3.3 and VSCode 1.45

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution since consumers of the component can still import the wrong things, but it's a step in the right direction. We metro bundler can find the proper files and we get type safety

Folder

- PlatformImage

  - index.tsx
  - PlatformImage.android.tsx
  - PlatformImage.d.ts
  - PlatformImage.ios.tsx

Testing.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import PlatformImage from '/ui/corex/PlatformImage';

const Testing = () => {
  return (
    <PlatformImage
      style={styles.prefixImage}
      borderRadius={styles.prefixImage.borderRadius}
      source={{
        uri: 'my uri',
        priority: 'high',
      }}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  prefixImage: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 40,
  },
});

export default Testing;
```

PlatformImage.d.ts

```
import { ImageStyle, StyleProp } from 'react-native';
import { Priority } from 'react-native-fast-image';

/**
 * An restricted list of props as we don't currently want to overcomplicate the code by supporting more
 * props than we actually need. If we need specific props that are supported by react-native.Image or
 * react-native-fast-image, we can add them as we need them.
 */
export interface PlatformImageProps {
  testID?: string;
  style?: StyleProp<ImageStyle>;
  source: {
    uri: string;
    /**
     * Only used in ios
     */
    priority: Priority;
  };
  /**
   *
   * Only used on android for border radius (since styles.borderRadius doesn't work for android). For ios, specify in styles.
   * Ideally the api for this component should be the same for both android & ios,
   * but this would mean preventing a styles.borderRadius from being used in ios in favor of using the
   * borderRadius prop, but this could be messy to code & maintain.
   */
  borderRadius?: number;
  resizeMode?: 'contain' | 'cover' | 'stretch' | 'center';
  /**
   * Invoked when load either succeeds or fails
   */
  onLoadEnd?: () => void;
}

declare const PlatformImage: React.ComponentType<PlatformImageProps>;

export default PlatformImage;
```

index.tsx

```
import PlatformImage from '/ui/corex/PlatformImage/PlatformImage';

export default PlatformImage;
```

PlatformImage.android.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { PlatformImageProps } from '/ui/corex/PlatformImage/PlatformImage';

/**
 * Components should never import this directly, but should rather import the index.tsx file
 */
const PlatformImage = ({
  testID,
  style,
  source,
  resizeMode = 'cover',
  borderRadius,
  onLoadEnd,
}: PlatformImageProps) => {
  console.log('running android');
  return (
    <Image
      testID={testID}
      // todo simon: fix this typescript error
      style={style}
      resizeMode={resizeMode}
      borderRadius={borderRadius}
      onLoadEnd={onLoadEnd}
      source={source}
    />
  );
};

export default PlatformImage;
```

PlatformImage.ios.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import { PlatformImageProps } from '/ui/corex/PlatformImage/PlatformImage';

/**
 * Components should never import this directly, but should rather import the index.tsx file
 */
const PlatformImage = ({
  testID,
  style,
  source,
  resizeMode = 'cover',
  onLoadEnd,
}: PlatformImageProps) => {
  console.log('running ios');
  return (
    <FastImage
      testID={testID}
      // todo simon: fix this typescript error
      style={style}
      resizeMode={resizeMode}
      onLoadEnd={onLoadEnd}
      source={source}
    />
  );
};

export default PlatformImage;
```

The mistake-prone import. Notice how vscode suggests a bunch of imports but we should only ever do `import PlatformImage from '/ui/corex/PlatformImage';`

[image]