# Relative import of platform specific ios/android typescript files for React-Native app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I have a component that has 2 different designs based on the platform for React-Native: `MyComponent.ios.tsx` and `MyComponent.android.tsx`.

Although when I import my component into `MyView.tsx`, it complains.

> MyView.tsx(5,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module './MyComponent'.

I have tried to modify my `tsconfig` file paths to the following:

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["*", "*.ios", "*.android"]
},
```

Although I still have the same problem.

Does any of you know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How are you importing `MyComponent`? Is it like the following `import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform specific import component in react native with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001050/platform-specific-import-component-in-react-native-with-typescript)

Answer (score 9):

Basically this approach won't work for one reason, once your ts files are transpiled, the relative path is not there anymore for the compiler to add ".ios" or ".android" and stop complaining, so the output will not work on react-native side when reading the pure JS.

I got it working by creating a typings (MyComponent.d.ts) file in the same folder, ex:

```
// This file exists for two purposes:
// 1. Ensure that both ios and android files present identical types to importers.
// 2. Allow consumers to import the module as if typescript understood react-native suffixes.
import DefaultIos from './MyComponent.ios';
import * as ios from './MyComponent.ios';
import DefaultAndroid from './MyComponent.android';
import * as android from './MyComponent.android';

declare var _test: typeof ios;
declare var _test: typeof android;

declare var _testDefault: typeof DefaultIos;
declare var _testDefault: typeof DefaultAndroid;

export * from './MyComponent.ios';
```

Comment: How are you importing this? When we import `import { component } from './MyComponent'`, it fails with a "Module not found: error can't resolve MyComponent".

Comment: Sorry I wrote this a year ago, I don't remember exactly what was the syntax, but it sounds like there might be some naming clash in your code, make sure that ./MyComponent is exporting MyComponent named class and so on

Comment: One thing to add here: the lines  `declare var _test: typeof ios;` and `declare var _test: typeof android;` are a trick to make the TypeScript compiler complain if `android` and `ios` diverge. The compiler however **only complains if** `skipLibCheck: false` **in** `tsconfig.json` (the default).

Comment: Thanks, went with this answer (kinda), and it works!  Example of it is here with FontFamilies.d.ts

https://github.com/quincycs/react-native-q-starter/commit/018d0d532ffc1ff87ca4f2babe61f8b8bdf9d892

Comment: Is the `_test` trick supposed to work with component too? I have a component with the same props definition and still, I get the `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type` error...

Comment: EDIT: "Is the _test trick supposed to work with CLASS component too?" (I have also have a functional component and it works for this one)

Comment: Why is the default export ios?

Answer (score 7):

Since TypeScript 4.7 there is now a new option to handle this for react native, but also web

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleSuffixes": [".android", ".ios", ""]
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleSuffixes

Comment: Wow, nice. This was it for me. After so much scouring.

Comment: Works for me, thanks. But for some reason doesn't work with json files :(