# How to correctly handle React Native & browser implementations in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am working on an app, with a web version (React DOM) and a Native one.

I created an internal "core" package with some core shared between the two platforms. For some modules in my core package, I need to have different implementations between the browser version and the native one.
For example I need to handle Base64 data, so I have a `base64.ts` file with the browser implementation:

```
const { atob, btoa } = window
export { atob, btoa }
```

And a React Native implementation in `base64.native.ts` using an external library :

```
export { decode as atob, encode as btoa } from "base-64"
```

And I can use it in my code like this:

```
import { btoa } from "core/base64"
```

This works fine on both platforms, as the React Native Metro bundler prefers the `.native.ts` file and uses it.

But the Typescript compiler emits an error when checking my React Native project because when it encounters the imports it resolves it with the web-based implementation (`base64.ts`) which triggers an error as `btoa` does not exist in the global space in React Native.

I have the same issue with other modules with different web & native implementations, like when the web module uses `window` and the RN module uses native functions.

What is the supported way of handling cross-platform implementations like this?

Comment: have look at this, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001050/platform-specific-import-component-in-react-native-with-typescript

Comment: Thanks, this was a good idea but even with a `btoa.d.ts` file TS tries to read the btoa.ts when imported from the RN project and emits and error