# How to use a module with types defined in a .d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

I started using `react-native-web`, and trying to do so with typescript. So far not much success. According [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001050/platform-specific-import-component-in-react-native-with-typescript), if I create a `.d.ts` file, typescript will get the types from there, but the values will be get from the not `.d.ts` files.

For me it throws `'Icon' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`.

I'm using it in a file called `Spinner.tsx`, importing it like: `import { Icon } from '../Icon';`, my file structure looks like:

```
Icon
  index.native.tsx
  index.web.tsx
  index.d.ts
```

`index.native.tsx`:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import RNVIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { IconProps } from './index.web';

export const Icon: FC<Omit<IconProps, 'style'> & { style: ViewStyle }> = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const RNVIName = name
    .replace(/io/i, '')
    .replace(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g, (str) => '-' + str.toLowerCase() + '-')
    .replace(/--/g, '-')
    .replace(/(^-)|(-$)/g, '');

  return <RNVIcon name={RNVIName} {...props} />
};
```

`index.web.tsx`:

```
import React, { CSSProperties, FC } from 'react';
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/io5';
import { ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

export type IconProps = {
  name: keyof typeof Icons;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
  style?: ViewStyle;
}

export const Icon: FC<Omit<IconProps, 'style'> & { style: CSSProperties }> = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const Component = Icons[name];

  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

`index.d.ts`:

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { IconProps } from "./index.web";

export type Icon = FC<IconProps>
```

I have tried with default export as well, no success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is partially that your input is resolving to the index.d.ts file. (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules)

That said, even if you had an index.ts file that exported Icon from each individual file, you would have a naming collision. The only workaround I'm aware of if you want to export a type and a value with the same name is to export them from the same file.